# Detect collision with an image, and an object on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have a game, where you try to catch money. There is a canvas which has a ball on it. There is also money spawning as images, OUTSIDE of the canvas. I am trying to check the x and y coordinates of the ball and the x and y coordinates of an image to be the same. Below is a link to my code:

Here is what I think is important to this:

```
function checkif(){

  for(var i = 0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('IMG').length; i++){

    var x1 = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[i].style.left;
    var x2 = x1.slice(0,x1.length-2)
    var y2 = poss;
    console.log(x2)
    console.log(y2)

    if(x2===x&&y2===y){
      score = score+1;
      document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
    }
  }
}
```

If it doesnt help, the code is down below in the JsFiddle link:
Thank you
https://jsfiddle.net/1fdo9ctp/

Comment: ANY other things that you suggest is widely accepted, thanks.

Comment: The example have issue loading "money.PNG". Please fix it

Comment: @MoorthyG I fixed it

Comment: Then, Please update jsfiddle link

Comment: @MoorthyG Sorry, I'm New to JSfiddle. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/1fdo9ctp/

Comment: You only get the location information of the main problem, money and character. However, you must include the width and height values ​​in the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to check if x and y positions are exactly the same which will almost never happen also it will not take the images binding box into account.

What you want to know is if the balls x intersects the money that it
ball.x > money.x // you want the balls position to be higher then the money position
&& ball.x < money.x + money.width // you want the ball position to be lower then the money x + the moneys width, also the same for y position.

So in summary:
The balls x,y should be inside the moneys box that is 
bigger then money.x and money.y and less then money.x+width and money.y+height

see this for examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection